# Need a Laptop Recommendation For Motorbike racing enthusiast

Tags: laptop

I have been tasked on finding a **prebuilt laptop** for a motorbike racing enthusiast.

You see, currently he takes a professional quality photos on his camera and then stores them to a external hard drive from the camera. He would like the ability to store the pictures on this laptop, so **capacity** is a big deal. He wants to be able to view the pictures he has taken. He likes the sound of being able to edit the images using Adobe Photoshop (which he has already purchased) though he says this is **not necessary.**

Finally his price range has a **max range of £300** (Their may be some leeway if the increased expense is worth the additional specs) The reason why the price range is so low is that if he drops the laptop in mud, or leaves his laptop behind accidently, it wont be a massive loss. 
He lives in the UK

I was looking at: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B076T7V685/ref=asc_df_B076T7V6851546945200000/?ascsubtag=s15472174731740yzza52421&tag=52421_iceleads-21&creative=22374&creativeASIN=B076T7V685&linkCode=df0

But the customer rating score was a 1 star.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: At that price you won't find much that makes it worth it or even meets the capacity requirements you want. I'd recommend spending a bit more and getting some kind of insurance or protection plan for accidents.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Okay so what would you recommend if the price range was raised.

Comment: Don't ask your question again simply because you didn't get any answers the first time. I've merged your duplicate question into this one.